# How do you say “act on” in a quantum-mechanical context in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, terminology, mathematics

My German is pretty good but I know very little of the terminology in Quantum Mechanics.

In Quantum Mechanics one often say something like

> the momentum operator **p** acts on the ket  |ψ>.

How would you say that in German?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In most cases in physics, *act on sth.* is translated by *auf etw. wirken*. So the phrase is:

> Der Impulsoperator **p** wirkt auf das Ket |ψ>.

For example, [in this Wikipedia article](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ortsoperator) you can read:

> In der Impulsdarstellung wirkt der Impulsoperator multiplikativ auf Impulswellenfunktionen [...].

Another possible construction I can think of is *auf etw. angewandt/angewendet werden*:

> Der Impulsoperator **p** wird auf das Ket |ψ> angewandt/angewendet.

Comment: Yep, same thing for group actions and similar in mathematics.

Comment: Sometimes also *auf den Ket-Vektor*. At least, we often said that alongside with *das Ket* in my QC course.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz It *is* actually a group action (by one of the generators of the Poincaré group). But my German is not enough to say that it's because of that, that one uses *wirken*.

Comment: Oh my, my lack of any Physics knowledge is embarrassing.

Comment: *Act on* for group actions is actually *auf etwas operieren*. I have never heard *auf etwas wirken* in mathematics. If that's really what they say in physics for a group action, then that would mean that terminology has diverged between the two fields.